# What are the technical hurdles that people face when writing transpiler from typescript to dart?

Tags: typescript, dart

What are the technical hurdles that people face when they want to write a transpiler from typescript to dart? 
When I look at the languages, both of them are capable of converting into js and both support static types as well as generics

Comment: Tip: *"why something doesn't exist"* is often an unproductive question to ask. It's probably simply because nobody sees a specific need for it.

Comment: There are many differences between Dart and TS that are difficult to translate from one language into the other automatically, this is why the transpiler was abandoned and Angular Dart and Angular TS split into 2 separately maintained projects.

Comment: @deceze not sure why is it opinion-based, there was a project which was alive and then it got archived. If it got archived and not developed anymore there should be reasons for it. I can not find the reason anywhere.

Comment: As @GünterZöchbauer mentioned there are many differences but when I look into the code I can't find any that can not be transpiled. For example, if you take a c code and can it be transpiled into javascript, the answer is no because there are pointers and memory operation possible in C++ while the same is not possible in javascript. Those are not opinions but facts. In the same way, I am looking for some facts, why something is not possible.

Comment: We don't know why a specific project lead decided to not develop the project further. Maybe it's technical reasons, maybe it's just that they could not find the time to do it anymore. Again, it's an unproductive question to ask and speculate about. If you want to know whether there are technical hurdles to compiling TS to Dart, that may be a worthwhile question. Rephrase your question then.

Comment: @Neo ts2dart only supported language constructs that were easy to translate. The Angular developers were limited to these parts of TS. This became too much of a burden, because it required additional abstractions and prevented writing efficient code which is a main priority when building frameworks.

Comment: @deceze updated the question.

Comment: There are many subtle differences. You mention generics. There are many issues with covariance, contravariance that are almost impossible to translate if they don't have the exactly same semantic (which differs quite a bit between Dart and TS). Another subtle differences are object instantiation - at what point during instantiation are instance members allowed to be accessed by code in the constructor. TS allows to access other members in field initializers, Dart doesn't. So while the languages are quite similar from a high altitude, they are quite different the closer you look.

Comment: JS only has very few such high-level language constructs and translation from TS/Dart to JS is more like translation to machine code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hey could you put this as an answer? I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many subtle differences. You mention generics. There are many issues with covariance, contravariance that are almost impossible to translate if they don't have the exactly same semantic (which differs quite a bit between Dart and TS). Another subtle differences are object instantiation - at what point during instantiation are instance members allowed to be accessed by code in the constructor. TS allows to access other members in field initializers, Dart doesn't. So while the languages are quite similar from a high altitude, they are quite different the closer you look.